# How to make two items align to the end in flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to implement a component like the image below. The behavior of the button should always align to the end of right most inner container even when the inner container wraps as window size gets small. The inner container should always align to the left so adding align-self: flex-end; for inner container is not the correct way. I ran out of idea about this. Please help! Thanks!

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.inner-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.inner-container>div {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn">Click Me!</button>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa(sample content in inner container)</div>
    <div>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb(sample content in inner container)</div>
    <div>cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc(sample content in inner container)</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WVXoNW

[image]

Comment: Will the widths of the inner elements always be known? This could be accomplished with JS but a CSS solution may be available if the widths are fixed.

Comment: If it is known, what should be the solution?

Comment: Perhaps you should check out CSS Grid https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns

Comment: Stumbled back on my first answer. It was really weak. I made an edit with a better one

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

My first solution was really lacking. Here is a better one:

```
/*The main container is a grid. It will create 1 column and 2 rows automaticaly*/

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  display: grid;
}

/* I place the button in the 1st row, 1st column and justify it at 
   the end of the row */

.btn {
  justify-self:end;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}

/* I place the inner-container in the 2nd row and 1 first column, */
/* Make it a grid */
/* And generate columns with auto-fit and minmax(). This way columns will stretch
   to the maximum or wrap if they are under the minimum */
/* The important thing here is that the width of the main container grid will 
   be determined by this second grid, so the button will always be aligned 
   with the largest row of the inner-container */

.inner-container {
  width: 100%;
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns : repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}
```

[Here is a pen](https://codepen.io/pi-L/pen/QWLyqKa) for this code.
The problem with flexbox here was that the container width doesn't resize when the wrapping happen. That's why I used 2 grids instead.

*note : I am working on a flexbox version with JS to adjust the width of the inner-container but it's more complicated than the solution I just presented.*

**Original**
Like Benjamin said grid might be the way to go.
**CSS :**

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 200px;
  justify-items: center;
}

.btn {
  justify-self:end;
}
```

That's all i changed, and I kept the display flex for the `inner-container` to keep the wrapping effect you wanted. There is no problem having a flex container inside a grid container.
There are tweaks that can be done to make it fit your needs more precisly.
 If you have questions or precisions don't hesitate to comment.